# How to fix problem with exec workspace bash in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, laradock

I'm using `docker-compose exec workspace bash` and after that I have error with **permission denied**. I can't understand, where is this file and what I need to do. So, you can see this trouble :

[image: permission denied error image]

Comment: What does the service definition (the `*.yml` file) of `workspace` look like, also the Dockerfile for the underlying image? Maybe the default user in the container is not `root` and therefore not privileged to run `bash`. Does it work if you add the `--privileged` flag?

Comment: it doesnt work with --privileged

Comment: What about the other points?

Comment: user sasha in docker group and defalut user is root in docker file

Comment: Please see my comment again and edit your question to contain a minimal reproducible example of your `docker-compose.yml`, so I can try to reproduce this error on my own machine to help you further.

Comment: did you tried with sudo ? also be sure that you builded/uped your container with sudo docker-compose up -d workspace, when you need to make some change use the laradock user: sudo docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash